# AWS ECS InvalidParameterExcpetion when calling the UpdateService Operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, deployment, amazon-ecs

I've been trying to setup CI/CD for my ECS cluster using jenkins. I followed this [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/set-up-a-build-pipeline-with-jenkins-and-amazon-ecs/) to do the same. But I'm getting this error:

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the
>   UpdateService operation: Invalid revision number. Number: 49

The command used to update the service is:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster ${CLUSTER_NAME} --service ${SERVICE_NAME} --task-definition ${TASK_FAMILY}:${TASK_REVISION} --desired-count ${DESIRED_COUNT}
```

Surprisingly, if I run the command from cli putting all the values, it runs successfully. I'm not sure what is wrong with the command.

**Edit 1**: The revision exists in the task-definition of AWS. I can see that specific revision from AWS console. As I've already mentioned the command runs successfully from cli using that specific revision.

**Edit 2**: I'm able to list-task-definitions using `aws ecs list-task-definitions` and I see that particular task definition in the list but I'm not able to describe that task definition using ${TASK_FAMILY}:${TASK_REVISION}. It gives me the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I figured out that `aws ecs describe-task-definition ${TASK_FAMILY}` was working while `aws ecs describe-task-definition ${TASK_FAMILY}:${TASK_REVISION}` was throwing the same `Invalid revision number error`.

So I tried the update-service command without using ${TASK_REVISION} variable like this:

```
aws ecs update-service --cluster ${CLUSTER_NAME} --service ${SERVICE_NAME} --task-definition ${TASK_FAMILY} --desired-count ${DESIRED_COUNT}
```

and it worked. It also uses the latest revision of the task definition.

Comment: Do you know if this works with ARN? or just the TaskFamily is okay? thanks

Comment: @IvánSánchez You just need to input the task family. Full ARN isn't required

Answer (score 0):

It seems that AWS CLI commands from within a bash-script file don't work if the task-definition or the service are full ARNs (contrary to the documentation). My script started working as soon as I stripped the task-definition and the service to their name(and revision number) by removing the arn:aws:..../ part.

Just to be clear, the full arn for task-definitions and service do work from the command prompt...just not from withinthe bash-script.

Comment: The reason why it doesnt work from bash script is bash adds double quotes to string and then the aws cli adds escape characters to the value.  Remove with this code bash 
task_def_arn=${task_def_arn%\"}
task_def_arn=${task_def_arn#\"}